# Setting PYTHONPATH for protocol buffers to import symbol_database

Tags: python, python-2.7, protocol-buffers, pythonpath

I don't understand why I cannot get python to pick up the google protocol buffer module that I have on my system.

With the source package of google protocol buffers version 2.6.1, I created the protobuf egg. Once installed using easy_install, everythings works fine. However, for our project, I don't want people to have to install the egg. So instead, I thought I'd have colleagues install a our-build-system-specific package that contains the python module in unpacked form and let python pick it up by specifying the PYTHONPATH. But it seems that no matter what I set the PYTHONPATH to, python doesn't see the package.

Contents of the unpacked module:

```
pkg
└── google
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    └── protobuf
        ├── compiler
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── plugin_pb2.py
        ├── descriptor_database.py
        ├── descriptor_pb2.py
        ├── descriptor_pool.py
        ├── descriptor.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── internal
        │   ├── api_implementation.cc
        │   ├── api_implementation_default_test.py
        │   ├── ...
        │   ├── wire_format.py
        │   └── wire_format_test.py
        ├── message_factory.py
        ├── message.py
        ├── pyext
        │   ├── cpp_message.py
        │   ├── descriptor.cc
        │   ├── ...
        │   ├── repeated_scalar_container.h
        │   └── scoped_pyobject_ptr.h
        ├── reflection.py
        ├── service.py
        ├── service_reflection.py
        ├── symbol_database.py <-----------------
        ├── text_encoding.py
        ├── text_format.py
```

No matter whether I set the PYTHONPATH to pkg/, pkg/google or pkg/google/protobuf, python fails to pick up symbol_database.py.

I use

```
python -c "from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database"
```

to test whether it works or not. I'm running python 2.7.

Why is this not working?

Comment: setting PYTHONPATH to pkg/ should be enough... But you need to set it right, ie. with full path.

Comment: I did that. I didn't want to bother you guys with the full path.
To be sure: it needs to point to the directory containing the \_\_init\_\_.py, right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ultimately solved it by making sure protoc matched the version of google.protobuf I'm using.  If you have a choice you should just use latest of both.  I needed to use a legacy google.protobuf module in a legacy system I'm modifying.

**Check version of python**

I didn't confirm this to be critical, but mention it just in case.  It's possible that when protoc runs, it will look to the default python interpreter's site-packages to see which version of protobufs you're using.  Make sure the default is the one you intend.  My system had two versions of python, and the default version had a newer version of protobufs.

**Match protoc version to protobufs module**

I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere, but it appears to be a requirement.  Maybe most developers are using latest so this rarely comes up.  The symbol_database import error you got happened because a more recent version of protobufs was assumed found when protoc generated the python interface.  But, when the import was run an older version of protobufs was available and symbol_database is not available in older versions.  Look in protobuf egg-info directory PKG-INFO file for version.

Another possible cause is that you're trying to use the *_pb2/3.py file generated on another system.

**Build older version of protoc**

Newer releases of protoc have binary releases, but not those prior to 3.0.  Fortunately, the code is old enough that GCC 4.4.x will build it successfully (those running on RH/CentOS will know why this is a blessing).  But unfortunately, the older builds are broken.  But not hard to fix:  run the commands in autogen.sh manually.  The main issue is the path to Google Test in this script is incorrect.